# How to connect my Python 3 code to the CSV files on my laptop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a homework problem and I thought I had it, but my program cannot read the files on my laptop so I get an error when I attempt to run my code. The files are all titled ssa(year).txt

The code I have tried seems to be all correct except for the portion that handles the files. None of my CSCI tutors could help.

```
import csv
my_list=[]

with open("ssa2017.txt", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    fields = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        row=[row[0],row[1],int(row[2]),row[3].lower().title(),int(row[4])]
        my_list.append(row)


def func1():
    state=input('Enter the State Abbreviation or just press enter: ')
    if state=='':
        state="US"
    year=input('Enter the years you want to search: ').split()
    y1=int(year[0])
    y2=int(year[1])

    my_dict={}
    for row in my_list:
        if row[2]>=y1 and row[2]<=y2 and state==row[0]:
            if row[3] not in my_dict.keys():
                my_dict[row[3]]=row[4]
            else:
                my_dict[row[3]]=my_dict[row[3]]+row[4]

    sorted_by_value = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1],reverse=True)
    print('Top 5 names')
    for i,key in enumerate(sorted_by_value):
            print(str(i+1)+': '+key[0]+' ('+str(key[1])+')')

def func2():
    name=input('Enter the name: ').lower().title()
    year=int(input('Enter the years: '))
    state=input('Enter the State Abbreviation or just press enter: ')

    my_dict={}

    for row in my_list:
        if year==row[2] and state==row[0]:
            if row[3] not in my_dict.keys():
                my_dict[row[3]]=row[4]
            else:
                my_dict[row[3]]=my_dict[row[3]]+row[4]

    sorted_by_value = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1],reverse=True)
    for i,key in enumerate(sorted_by_value):
        if key[0]==name:
            print('\nThe name',name,'was in position',i+1)

while True:
    print('\n1) Search by Year/Location\n2) Search by name\n3) Quit')
    choice=input('Select the option: ')
    if choice=='1':
        func1()
    elif choice=='2':
        func2()
    elif choice=='3':
        break
    else:
        print('Please select the valid option.')
```

I AM NOT TRYING TO GET YOU DO DO MY HW, BUT THIS IS WHAT IS EXPECTED. 
home / study / engineering / computer science / computer science questions and answers / in python 3 the u.s. social security administration publishes lists of baby names for every ...
Question: IN PYTHON 3 The U.S. Social Security Administration publishes lists of baby names for every year ...
IN PYTHON 3

The U.S. Social Security Administration publishes lists of baby names for every year since 1880.
The data for each year is stored in a separate file. The files all have the format

Name,Sex(M/F),Number

The Number is the number of children given the name in that year. These files are edited so that they are shorter and only include names with >= 100 entries for that year.

You are to create a program to provide information from these files:

-For each year of data needed, your program must read the file 'ssaxxx.txt' where xxxx is the year needed.

-The data file format is consistent and for this assignment you DO NOT have to check for errors in the data files

-You do no need to check each user input (choice and years) for errors and handle those without crashing

-The program must include a function called name(). This function takes two arguments. The first is the year as an integer and the second is the type of name to search for: 'M' for male, 'F' for female, and 'E' for everyone. The function must return both the most popular name for that year and the number of times the name was given.

To develop/test the program, you need to get the data files from 1980 to 2018, These can be found in the files section below in a zip file. You DO NOT need to upload the data files to Zybooks (only upload your program), they are only for you development purposes.

The program must offer the following options

-The first option will scan the files and print the most popular name for each year (regardless if it is male or female) along with the number of that name given for each year

-The second option will look at all all the years and find the most popular name overall and the overall total for that name

-The third option is like the first one, except it will print the most popular male name for each year along with the number of the name given for each year

-The fourth option will print the most popular female name for each year along with the total number of that name given for that year

After each option (other than quit), ask for a starting and ending year.

[This is what the SSA file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlvRW.png)

[Here is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqiog.png)

HERE IS A PORTION OF THE FILE:

```
Aiden,M,11259
Cielo,F,143
Zephaniah,M,136
Allyson,F,634
Jessa,F,307
Omar,M,1639
Micaela,F,239
Annalee,F,287
Nolan,M,5375
Ronnie,M,238
Nico,M,747
Milani,F,536
Kaila,F,133
Zakari,M,106
Emilie,F,248
Rex,M,428
Luciana,F,782
Karla,F,552
Misael,M,243
Zendaya,F,258
Rayna,F,391
Krystal,F,200
Nathaly,F,213
Brielle,F,2880
Daenerys,F,110
Galilea,F,527
Aspyn,F,178
Giovanni,M,2783
```

Comment: Can you show how `ssa2017.txt` looks like, also what error do you get when you run this code?

Comment: Add the file to the question!

Comment: I added it, i cannot copy it because it is too large but i added a screenshot I also screenshoted the error msg

Comment: You can always add part of the txt file in the question, also paste the csv and error here, and not post images!

Comment: I added a portion of the specific file you asked for

Comment: In the future, please paste the error as text, not an image. The error is telling you it can't find the file, so there may be a difference in the names (possibly file extensions), or it's in a different folder. Can you provide the output (as text) of `ls` or `dir`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your `ssa2017.txt` is not in the same folder with the script you are executing.

You can investigate the absolute path which Python looking for the `ssa2017.txt` by adding these lines at the top of your script:

```
import os
full_path = os.path.abspath('ssa2017.txt')
print(full_path)
```

If the `full_path` variable here is not the same as your path to `ssa2017.txt`, it's the reason why your Python script can not access the text file.

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentions states that it cannot find the file `ssa2017.txt`. By default, python tries to look for a file you are trying to open in the same folder you are trying to run the script in. So you need to provide the whole path of the file.

So you can either do

```
with open("<folder_with_text_files>/ssa2017.txt", 'r') as f:
    #do stuff
```

Or if you have all your files in the same folder, you can use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to list them and then open it

```
import os

folder_with_files = '/Users/devesingh/Downloads'

#List all files in folder
for file in os.listdir(folder_with_files):
    #If the file has ssa in it
    if 'csv' in file:
        #Get the full file path and use it to open
        full_file_path = os.path.join(folder_with_files, file)
        with open(full_file_path, 'r') as f:
            #do stuff
```

Comment: After you open your file, you can debug your code further @ElliottLambert Also please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you :)

Comment: Sure thing @ElliottLambert

Comment: Hi @ElliottLambert , If this worked for you, Please consider marking my answer as accepted :)